# JS turn undefined value into empty string

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm using the `Object.assign()` to copy values to an object:

```
const { one, two, three } = attributes;

return Object.assign( props, { 
  "data-one": one,
  "data-two": two,
  "data-three": three   
} );
```

If the value of a property is empty it returns undefined. I want it to return an empty string or ideally not copy any empty properties.

I tried this:

```
const { one, two, three } = attributes;

var oneValue = one ? one : "";
var twoValue = two ? two : "";
var threeValue = three ? three : "";

return Object.assign( props, { 
  "data-one": oneValue,
  "data-two": twoValue,
  "data-three": threeValue   
} );
```

It works by sending empty values instead of undefined but doesn't seem very fancy. Is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**@CyberJunkie**, You can fix it by using the concept of **Object destruction** as follows:

> **Note**: Visit [Destructuring assignment](https://javascript.info/destructuring-assignment) and [Destructuring assignment - Mozilla.org's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to read about **Destructing objects**.

```js
function getObj(attributes)
{
 const { one: newOne = '', two: newTwo = '', three: newThree = '' } = attributes;

 // var oneValue = one ? one : "";
 // var twoValue = two ? two : "";
 // var threeValue = three ? three : "";
 var props = {four: "The four", six: "The six"};

 return Object.assign( props, { 
   "data-one": newOne,
   "data-two": newTwo,
   "data-three": newThree  
 } );
}

var prettyObj = JSON.stringify(getObj({one: "ObjData1.1", two: 'ObjData2', three: 'ObjData3'}), null, 4);
console.log(prettyObj)
/*
 {
     "four": "The four",
     "six": "The six",
     "data-one": "ObjData1.1",
     "data-two": "ObjData2",
     "data-three": "ObjData3"
 }
*/

prettyObj = JSON.stringify(getObj({one: "ObjData1.2", two: 'ObjData2'}), null, 4);
console.log(prettyObj)
/*
 {
     "four": "The four",
     "six": "The six",
     "data-one": "ObjData1.2",
     "data-two": "ObjData2",
     "data-three": ""
 }
*/

prettyObj = JSON.stringify(getObj({one: "ObjData1.2"}), null, 4)
console.log(prettyObj)
/*
 {
     "four": "The four",
     "six": "The six",
     "data-one": "ObjData1.2",
     "data-two": "",
     "data-three": ""
 }
*/
```

Finally, you can have a look at the code below that I have executed on **NODE REPL** as it presents the difference between `const { one: newOne = '', two: newTwo = '', three: newThree = '' } = attributes;` and `const { one = '', two = '', three = '' } = attributes;` statements.

```
H:\RishikeshAgrawani\Projects\Stk\UndefinedValue>node
>
> // Example 1
undefined
>
> attributes = {one: "ObjData1.2", two: 'ObjData2'}
{ one: 'ObjData1.2', two: 'ObjData2' }
>
> const { one: newOne = '', two: newTwo = '', three: newThree = '' } = attributes;
undefined
>
> one
ReferenceError: one is not defined
>
> newOne
'ObjData1.2'
>
> newTwo
'ObjData2'
>
> newThree
''
>
> // Example 2
undefined
> attributes2 = {one: "ObjData1.2", two: 'ObjData2'}
{ one: 'ObjData1.2', two: 'ObjData2' }
>
> const { one = '', two = '', three = '' } = attributes;
undefined
> one
'ObjData1.2'
> two
'ObjData2'
> three
''
>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You could define default values when using destructuring.

```js
const attributes = { one: 'one' };
const { one = '', two = '', three = '' } = attributes;
const props = {}

console.log(Object.assign( props, { 
  "data-one": one,
  "data-two": two,
  "data-three": three
}));
```

Finally, if you have lots of common behavour you could just name properties you want to copy and write a loop.

Answer (score -1):

```
 function assignNotUndefined(target, obj) {
   for(const key of Object.keys(obj)) {
    if(obj[key] !== undefined)
     target[key] = obj[key];
   }
   return target;
 }
```

Usable as:

```
const { one, two, three } = attributes;

return assignNotUndefined( props, { 
 "data-one": one,
 "data-two": two,
 "data-three": three   
});
```